# Play sound on button click (Angular)

Tags: angular, audio, click

I'm trying to play a sound when a link is clicked

This is what I have, however, it doesn't work and seems to slow the browser down significantly whenever I have it added into the files

HTML:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/tomato2" class="tomato" (click)="playAudio()">
  <img class="tomato_1" src="https://freepngimage.com/content/uploads/images/tomato-7866.png" />
</a>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html'
})

export class CatalogViewComponent {
    playAudio(){
      let audio = new Audio();
      audio.src = "http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mpc/audio/CHINA_1.mp3";
      audio.load();
      audio.play();
      this.playAudio();
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you click that button has to be downloaded first before it is played? If it is one of your sounds, you may want to consider including it with the assets of your app.

Comment: I think you should load the audio on `ngInit` and use the `playAudio` to start playback. Also, you have a recursive call as the last line `this.playAudio();`, probably why the browser slows down.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular 2+ this will helpful.

```
<audio #ref src="https://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1964&type=mp3"></audio>

<button (click)="ref.play()">▶️ play</button>
<button (click)="ref.pause()">⏸ pause</button>
```

[StackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-audio?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)